# Subtract rows of data from rows of data in the same colum

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, rows, subtraction

I am just starting to use python for my Data Science class so I know basically nothing about it aside from the basics.

[image]

I have approximately 600 rows of data, half of which are data from one country, the other half from another. They are displayed as all the data from country 1 first then followed by all the data from country 2. Is it possible to add a column, subtracting one set of data from country 1 from the same set of data from country 2. I hope I'm making sense.

This is a snippet of the whole table of data. Both boxed values are from the same column. I basically want to subtract the boxed values below from the boxed values above.

Comment: can you show us the column names?

Comment: What is your data file format? Text file, xls table?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we probably need to know if the number of rows for each country is the same. If you have already know this beforehand then no problem if not you can check by doing this:

```
df.groupby('country_name_column').count()
```

If they aren't the same you probably have to do some extra processing for your data. If they are then you can easily substract the values by doing operations on the Series for each country by filtering with Boolean indexing.

```
diff = df[df['country_name_column'] == 'Kuwait']['boxed_value_column'] - df[df['country_name_column'] == 'Panama']['boxed_value_column']
diff.head()
```